# Howe to mass update elastic search from S3 file

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3

I have a 10GB file sitting in amazon s3 location and want to insert all records into Elastic search (roughly 100 million records). I tried bulk updater in my scala code which ran in aws instance. Is there any approach that  I should take to insert through the code or should I use some aws utilities?

Comment: just wonder why bulks didn't work? there is [plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-s3.html) for logsatsh for example

Comment: is there any difference between elastic search bulkload api and sdks from python , java which supports bulk upload?

Comment: Not sure I understood your question. For example in java there's a choice which communication to use https://www.elastic.co/blog/state-of-the-official-elasticsearch-java-clients.   Other use REST API over http. There couldn't be any real difference. Http clients should follow the same rules to talk to bulk api